# What is the simplest way to create a form in java swing?

Tags: java, swing

I need advise about layout manager in swing for such form:

```
   Label1 TextField1
   Label1 TextField1
   ButtonWideAsForm
```

Can you tell me what layout to use ?

Comment: `BorderLayout` is the easiest to start with in my opinion. with some "hacking" your alyout is also possible

Comment: Learn GridBagLayout.  It is difficult to learn, but works very well.  It is worth the time to learn.

Comment: I actually tend to use `Box` when I want simplicity in code.  Other layouts are better though, look into using an IDE and a GUI layout tool, like NetBeans and Matisse.

Comment: I use GridBagConstraints for just about everything. Works pretty well for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example of just the GUI the way you described it using GridBagConstraints:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TestGUI {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("label1");
        JTextField text1 = new JTextField();
        JTextField text2 = new JTextField();
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("label2");
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button");

        text1.setColumns(10);
        text2.setColumns(10);

        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(label1, constraints);
        constraints.gridx = 1;
        panel.add(text1, constraints);
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(label2, constraints);
        constraints.gridx = 1;
        panel.add(text2, constraints);
        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 2;
        constraints.gridwidth = 2;
        constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        panel.add(button1, constraints);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

The gridx and gridy are relatively simple and self explanatory, they just say what row and column the component is supposed to be in. They key is the fill and the gridwidth. This tells the layout manager to position the button to take up 2 cells and to fill any extra space that is in the row, which achieves the full width effect.

Comment: Thank for demo. Is it possible to allign labels to the right and textfields to the left?

Comment: Yeah, just switch their `gridx` values. So `text1` would have `gridx = 0` and `label1` would have `gridx = 1` and the same for `label2` and `text2`.

Comment: @JaySmith Sure it is. Take a look at GridBagConstraints.anchor possible values (in this case you just need to set GridBagConstraints.EAST for label's anchor and GridBagConstraints.WEST for textfield's anchor)

Comment: @Steampunkery I think the op is talking about aligning components inside the grid cell.

Comment: Ah. Yes, you can do that with anchor, like @Ansharja said

Comment: @JaySmith,  `Is it possible to...` why don't you try to fix it yourself? You learn by trying, not expecting people to spoon feed the code for you. There is no way you took any time to read the API to find out how the various constraints work. Start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for example of using the various constraints. Experiment. Whatever you try will be useful for future layouts as well.

Comment: Thanks to all. I=With gridbag layout I achived what I wanted